# custom keyboard in iOS 8 access

Tags: ios8, custom-keyboard

is a custom keyboard in iOS 8 able to get access to the **iPhone camera** ??

because i heard that it can't get access to the **microphone**

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot.

As Apple documentation states:

> Because of its focused role in the system, an app extension is ineligible to participate in certain activities. An **app extension cannot**:
>
> - Access a sharedApplication object, and so cannot use any of the
>     methods on that object
> - Use any API marked in header files with the `NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE` macro, or similar unavailability macro, or any API in an unavailable framework.
> - **Access the camera or microphone on an iOS device**
> - Perform long-running background tasks
> - Receive data using AirDrop

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2